# Using target="_blank" for anchor no longer returns a validation error in a html5 doctype

Tags: css, validation, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it alright use to target=_blank in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198788/is-it-alright-use-to-target-blank-in-html5)

I have this.

```
<a href="#foo" class="external" target="_blank" title="foo">www.foo.com</a>
```

Previosuly the `target="_blank"` used to retrun a validation error. If I remmber correctly it used to state a deperecated error with the doctypes prior to html5. However in html5 doctypes this is no longer a validation error and therfore javascript was used instead.

Does it mean it's no longer deprecated and I do not need javascript any more to achive this functionality?

Comment: @TimMedora: Right. Delete or close?

Comment: I say close, not delete. I don't think it hurts to have a question 2 years newer which points to the old one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

> The [target](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/a.html#a.attrs.target) attribute on the a element was deprecated in a previous version of HTML, but is no longer deprecated, as it useful in Web applications, particularly in combination with the [iframe](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/iframe.html#iframe) element.

http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/a.html