# how to open a local html file in a separate browser tab instead of being opened by the jupyter server as text

Tags: markdown, jupyter-lab

I want to place a link to a local html file that should be opened into a different browser tab from Jupyter Lab, instead of being opened by the jupyter server as text.

Currently if I do [link description](link_file.html) then it is opened as text by Jupyter Lab. Note that I prefer a markdown solution instead of something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22445217/python-webbrowser-open-to-open-chrome-browser).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open link in new tab on html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17711146/how-to-open-link-in-new-tab-on-html)

Comment: As a reminder, Markdown is a subset of HTML. As Markdown does not offer a way to do this directly, you then need to fall back to HTML See the possible duplicate linked above for how to do this in HTML.

Comment: Perhaps a better duplicate would be [Open new tab on link markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40026947/866026), which addresses Markdown directly.